# Combine Tls12 and Tls13

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.3

If I remember correctly, up to .Net 4.6.1 there was a combined security setting

```
SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12
```

to select best supported security. This offered possibility to use Tls12 if available and fall back to others. As Tls and Tls11 are considered insecure, this now also offers downgrade attacks and should no longer be used.

The fallback idea is not that bad as Tls13 is not yet supported on many platforms. Is it possible to use the same approach with current encryption standards:

```
SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13
```

BTW: SslProtocols.None might be best but I don't like it as it is not clear which protocol gets used.

Comment: Why are you asking? The [oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/), which does what you want automatically. What you call `up to .Net 4.6.1 there was a combined security setting` was a critical security hole *preventing* the automatic use of TLS 1.3, while forcing the use of *weaker* algorithms

Comment: Which OS are you targeting? TLS 1.3 was added in Windows 11. Trying to hard-code it in older versions won't change anything, it will only re-enable older, weaker algorithms

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The idea is to use best security if available, fallback to 2nd best and avoid SslProtocols.None (as it is completely unclear what it actually does.)

Comment: What you want is already available out of the box and requires no hard-coding. This worked even in 4.6.1 except for WCF. You don't have to hard-code anything. You'll find a *lot* of relevant questions from 7 years ago. Update to a recent runtime and *remove* all attempts to hard-code TLS

Comment: In fact, you may not be able to use 4.6.1 at all as supported Windows 10/11 versions come with supported .NET runtimes. Any machine you target has 4.6.2 already, either out of the box or as part of an update

Comment: No the best thing is not to set it at all, unless on a lower version than 4.6.2. Allow the OS to decide the best option

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)